# Is there a way to download a Skype broadcast on Mac?

Tags: macos, video, skype

I was sent a link to the video recording made in Skype, and can watch it on the web-based player.

I'd like to download the broadcast to play it on a different device, process it via other tools.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: use the link on  the other device or skype on the other device?

Comment: I don't know if I got the question right. So theres a link where you can see a Skype broadcast and you want to download it from the web? is it right ?

Answer (score 4):

Sure - there are all sorts of tools to download video when you have a URL.

One that's super easy for me and should be for anyone that has spent a little time learning the bash shell / command - line in the Terminal.app is

- https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/

Rather than downloading that alone, I would recommend you start with Homebrew package manager:

- https://brew.sh

If you are going to struggle with the command line - this makes it easier to know you've got a good setup, then install the youtube-dl tool (and it's works to download far more then just YouTube, but that's the origin / elephant in the room place where people want to get videos these days).

```
brew install youtube-dl
```

Then just copy / paste the URL to see about the Skype download. If you prefer an app you can click, I'd start with the VLC player and open the network location to see how it sees the Skype video.

- https://www.videolan.org

Comment: To the answer I'd like to add that although `youtube-dl` is able to download streaming videos from most of the popular website, it isn't a generic video stream download tool. The list of supported sites can be determined by running `youtube-dl --list-extractors`. Unlisted sites are treated as generic and `youtube-dl` attempts to download the video stream from such sites, but may fail to do so.